# What is the best way to run a child process for limited time

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops

I am making a new script(p.py)for my Raspberry Pi and i am trying to combine 2 python scripts named Final.py and A.py . I want to execute the Final.py for about 5 seconds and then kill it and proceet to A.py, run it for 25 seconds and kill it and repeat the whole process endlessly. However, both of the scripts are looped and i don't know how to end these processes. Here the p.py code:

```
import subprocess
import time
execfile('Finaaal.py') #looped script 1
time.sleep(5.0)
subprocess.call(['./1.sh']) #this kills Finaaal.py
execfile('A.py') #looped script 2
time.sleep(25.0)
subprocess.call(['./2.sh']) #this kills A.
```

Does anyone know any better ideas or a better way to fix this? Everything would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you simply make Finaaal.py a 5 second script?

Comment: And may I ask you how do i do that

Comment: Calling `execfile` is going to run the other script _within this process_, which means there's no way for `1.sh` to kill it without killing your control script.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged this both 2.7 and 3.x? Do you need a solution that works in both?

Comment: Yes i wanted to know for both versions. But how could i make this a 5sec script ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make any sense. You run the sub-scripts like this:

```
execfile('Finaaal.py') #looped script 1
```

But [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) just runs that script in the current interpreter, not as a separate program. Which means there's no way script `1.sh` could possibly kill `Finaaal.py` without also killing the controller script.

The answer is simple—you've already imported [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), you just need to use it to run the sub-scripts instead of using `execfile`. And then you don't even need `1.sh` and `2.sh` scripts; you can just `kill` the processes directly:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'Finaaal.py'])
time.sleep(5.0)
p.kill()
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'A.py'])
time.sleep(5.0)
p.kill()
```

Since you've tagged your question both `python-2.7` and `python3.x`, you probably need to think about which Python should be used to run the sub-scripts. Using [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) means it'll be the same one used to run the controller script, which is usually what you want (but if not, obviously do something different there, whether that's "hardcode `python3`" or "whatever the shbang says" or whatever's appropriate).

(Since you appear to be on POSIX, you can even modify `Finaaal.py` and `A.py` to catch the `SIGKILL` and do some clean shutdown if you want. Or, if you want a hard shutdown instead of having that option, use `terminate` instead.)

Comment: then `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'Finaaal.py'])` part is worth an upvote, reusing the current interpreter to run sub-scripts.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Probably not worth an upvote until I actually explain it, though… I'll edit it.

Comment: don't explain _me_, I got it :)

Comment: So it worked thanks!!! Do you also know how to loop this p.py script ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I meant explain it to the OP, not to you. :)

Comment: @Tony The same way you loop anything else—e.g., take the whole thing and indent it under a `while True:`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I rreally appreciate helpfull people like you!

Comment: @Tony Also, this question has been closed as a dup. This means there's an existing question (two of them, in fact) that have answers that should apply to your problem, and that have been upvoted by multiple people over time. So definitely go read them; they've probably covered things I haven't.

Comment: @abarnert another good reason to use the python executable is when using Windows. Just using the script name doesn't cut it, because windows doesn't care about shebangs... you'd have to use `shell=True` (eeeek!!) or `cmd /c ` prefix (not portable). `sys.executable` rocks because it's super-portable (well, except if the script is frozen using `cx_freeze` or `py2exe`)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, I purposely didn't explain what to do for that particular "something different" case, because… it's hairy, and probably irrelevant for the OP. If you have a use case that's specifically about Windows, usually the answer is something to do with `py.exe`.